# Connecting a 12.5VDC switch output to a GlobalStar SmartOne GPS unit

Tags: switches, voltage-regulator, gps

I have a device (hermetically sealed onboard computer on a diesel generator) with a power switch that is connected directly to a lead acid battery (~12.5VDC). I would like to trigger a gps device when the on switch is closed. Although I cannot find the data sheet for the gps unit, I suspect the I/O input on the GPS unit is max 5 VDC.

If I wanted to provide a easily patched in solution (something that is easy to install for a laymen with thick fingers), what is the best solution? My thought was some type of screw terminal voltage regulator.

Comment: The computer is not actually hermetically sealed :P, I just mean I can't touch it, and so far the on switch is by far the most physically accessible part of the whole system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple voltage divider should do the trick:

[image]

It seems like a 20k on top and 30k on the bottom should give you 5V in the middle that you need.

Now is this battery also connected to an alternator?  At least in a car that means the DC voltage is around 14V or so when it's running.  If that was the case a quick fix would be to put a 5V zener diode in parallel with the bottom resistor.

### Vreg

Also if you want to go the Vreg route, this little adapter might help you.

[image]

Here's the [link](http://www.dimensionengineering.com/products/vreg-breakout) to the site that sells them.  It looks like  you can choose from their regulators you want to use with it like [this](http://www.dimensionengineering.com/products/de-sw050) 5V one.  Although I'm sure you can jam any similar packaged 3 pin regulator in there.

Comment: ... all of which misses the point that if you check the unit's data sheet, it is actually capable of accepting 12V in the first place.

Comment: Really where in that datasheet does it say the TTL level inputs accept 12V?

Comment: Does it? If so, then this question is moot! @DaveTweed do you have a link to the actual datasheet?

Answer (score 0):

The data sheet is on [this page](http://www.globalstar.com/shop/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=79); just scroll down to the bottom.

However, I don't see any additional information on the "Combined Serial, LP I/O Cable", which is probably the only other piece you need.

Comment: Ya I found this. They also have a "Datasheet" located here http://www.globalstar.com/en/index.php?cid=4340